# How do I create a fetch request for a stock exchange API that presents the search as a list on the page?

Tags: javascript

How do I create a fetch request so that when the user inputs a stock symbol and search button is clicked, the website loads 10 search results from a NASDAQ API link and presents them as a list on the webpage?

Each item in the list should show the company name and symbol (AAPL for Apple)

```
//search input
const searchBar = document.getElementById("searchBar");

//List results
const searchButton = document.getElementById("submit");

searchBar.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});


//console.log(fetch(url));
console.log(fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()));

// Fetch url
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
      console.log(data[i]);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a onclick actionListener, get the access token by invoking

```
POST https://dataondemand.nasdaq.com/api/v1/authenticate
```

Followed by pass that token in the header and consume

```
POST https://dataondemand.nasdaq.com/api/v1/quotes/async
```

via async call. Note :Pass the symbols fitler in the post data call.